# What is the nodejs equivalent library of the ruby gem 'devise'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, rubygems, user-accounts

Looking for a nodejs library that can help make the process of creating user profiles easier for a web application

Answer (score 8):

[Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) is really good for it. More information is available [here](http://passportjs.org/).

Comment: Passport is only pluggable authentication middleware. It does not offer a user model and validation, recovery, registration, invitations, tracking or automated timeouts. Stay with rails & devise if you can.

Comment: Passport is no replacement for Devise

Comment: https://github.com/carvalhoviniciusluiz/mongoose-devise